# How can I use Histogram and Histogram3D on an image?

Tags: image-processing, image, histograms, homework

I have a `.jpg` image named `r`.
I am using the following code to plot a histogram:

```
r // ImageData // Flatten // Histogram
```

Is it correct?
Another task is to apply `Histogram3D`. However, I am unable to use `Histogram3D`. I know I need to convert my data into a 2D list but I am having difficulties figuring out how.

Comment: Have you seen `ImageHistogram[]` already?

Comment: This seems to be related to some homework, I assume, as there is another new user with almost [the same problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156045/10397), none has managed to explain why they want to use `Histogram3D` with and RGB array of data.

Comment: @J.M., I did look at `ImageHistogram`. This is part of an assignment and `Histogram3D` is required. I need to manipulate the data into a 2D list in order to be able to use `Histogram3D`. Nothing that I tried worked as I am ending up with a 3D list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ImageHistogram

If you have a colour image, such as

```
img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Apples"}], 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As mentioned by JM, there is [`ImageHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageHistogram.html)

```
ImageHistogram[img]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Dimensions

But for some reason you have NOT explained, you want to use [`Histogram3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram3D.html), which takes arguments in the form of list of pairs of values.

Then the number of colour channels is 3

```
ImageChannels[img]
```

That implies that the dimensions of the data array, is the dimensions of the pixel array and depth 3.

```
Dimensions[ImageData[img]]
(* {67, 100, 3} *)
```

So the data is incompatible.

### Re-arrange

Of course you could rearrange the data.

```
Partition[Flatten[ImageData[img]], 2]
```

or

```
ArrayReshape[
 ImageData[img]
 , {Times @@ Dimensions[ImageData[img]]/2, 2}
 ]
```

but then you are mixing the RGB values and

```
{{r[1], g[1], b[1]}, {r[2], g[2], b[2]}, {r[3], g[3], b[3]}, {r[4], 
  g[4], b[4]}, {r[5], g[5], b[5]}, ... , {r[n], g[n], b[n]}}
```

becomes

```
{{r[1], g[1]}, {b[1], r[2]}, {g[2], b[2]}, {r[3], g[3]}, {b[3], 
  r[4]}, ... , {g[n], b[n]}}
```

### Manipulate

you can process or manipulate the data to create some other set, for example averaging two channels

```
Map[{First[#], Mean[Rest[#]]} &,
 Flatten[ImageData[img], 1]
 ]
```

you will get something like

```
{{r[1], (b[1] + g[1])/2}, {r[2], (b[2] + g[2])/2},..., {r[n], (b[n] + g[n])/2}
```

### Histogram3D

Whatever you did, then you can apply the `Histogram3D` to the array woth dimensions {n,2}

```
Dimensions@Map[{First[#], Mean[Rest[#]]} &,
  Flatten[ImageData[img], 1]
  ]
(* {6700, 2} *)

Histogram3D[
 Map[{First[#], Mean[Rest[#]]} &,
  Flatten[ImageData[img], 1]
  ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: True, the data is incompatible, but like I mentioned in the comments `Histogram3D` is a requirement in the question and I know that I need to manipulate the data. The methods you suggest work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations rhermans! You get an A on this assignment!

Comment: @bills What do I need to do for A+?

Comment: @bills Well, please let the students know that a better explanation of the problem is normally required here. I actually wanted to vote to close the question first...